How to enable JavaScript in URLSession.shared.data in Swift
When I try to fetch a JSON from an API with the following code:
let (retrieved_data, error) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: apiURL!)

I get an response telling me that:
First, I need to use IE10 or later

Your Browser is not supported. Please use IE10 or later!

and Second that I need to enable JavaScript

You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

So far I have not found the solution to enable those features. Any advice is appreciated.

It sounds like you aren't hitting the correct URL.  The messages you are describing sound like part of a default error page being returned by the web server. You don't need to (and indeed, can't) enable Javascript, neither is the browser version relevant since you aren't using a browser.

The first error is indicating that the site is using the user agent to determine the browser. This is extremely poor web design, but you'll have to take that up with the developer of the page. You can modify your User-Agent header on URLRequest to change what the app presents to the web server. For details see Changing the userAgent of NSURLConnection.
The second situation is not something URLSession can do. It fetches raw bytes from a web server. It does not interpret those bytes, and it cannot execute JavaScript found on the page. It won't even interpret HTML in order to discover additional page resources. This is not URLSession's job. It just fetches data from a URL.
To interact with a web page as a web browser, a common approach is to use a WKWebView. You can use .load() to load a request, evaluating JavaScript, etc., and you can then use evaluateJavaScript() and related methods to execute arbitrary JavaScript inside of the WKWebView and interact with the page, and WKScriptMessageHandler to receive callbacks to Swift. This is a fairly in-depth topic, and you will generally need a modest level of knowledge of JavaScript and HTML.
How complex this is, and exactly how to go about it, depends heavily on your precise goal and the web page. Interacting with a simple JavaScript-rendered page, and fetching the final contents is not overly difficult. Trying to interact with a complex web app can be a massive project.
